# Histogram not showing when based on reactive user input Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to show a histogram based the selection from a selectInput. The output should be hist(dataframe$feature1) depending on what feature they choose, but nothing is showing. Here is my code.

ui.R

```
selectInput("variableFeat", "Choose Feature", c("feature1", "feature2", "feature3"))
```

server.R

```
 output$feature <- reactive({

    dataframe$input$variableFeat


})


output$hist <- renderPlot({

    hist(feature(), main="Histogram of Selected Feature", xlab="Selected Feature", ylab="Frequency", col="orange")

})
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a histogram, create the vector of values first, based on user input then use if statements to choose which feature to view:

server.R

```
output$hist <- renderPlot({

   vectorOfValues1 <- dataFrame$FEATUREtoPLOT1
   vectorOfValues2 <- dataFrame$FEATUREtoPLOT2


if (input$variableFeat == "Choice1") {

    hist(vectorOfValues1}

}

if (input$variableFeat == "Choice2") {

    hist(vectorOfValues2}

}}

})
```

ui.R

```
outputPlot("hist")
```